# how to disable compositing nodes for selected frames?

Tags: rendering, animation, node-editor

In the beginning, I have used the Glare compositing nodes for frames 0 to 160. After frame 160, I wanted to animate other objects without the Glare compositing nodes, but when I rendered the whole video out, the nodes were applied to the entire animation. Is there any way to disable the compositing nodes for selected frames? (for my case, after frame 160)

Answer (score 1):

The quick way is via using the time-node. [image]